# Cannot read property 'title' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get the details of a single post but i keep getting this error; ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateRenderer].
Although the data is being gotten correctly in console.log but its not showing on the page itself. when i do {{post?.title}}, the error goes away but the results still don't appear on the page but shows correctly in console.log

Ionic Framework: v4
OS Platform: Windows 10

post.service

```
getAllPosts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}`).pipe(
      map(results => {
        console.log('Raw: ', results);
        return results['posts'];
      })
    );
  }

  getPost(postId: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/${postId}`);
  }
```

post.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { PostService } from '../post.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.page.scss'],
})
export class PostPage implements OnInit {
  loadedPost: any;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const postId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('postId');

    this.postService.getPost(postId).subscribe(result => {
      console.log('details: ', result);
      this.loadedPost = result;
    });
  }
}
```

post.page.html

```
<ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-title text-center>{{loadedPost.title}}</ion-card-title>
</ion-card-header>
```

console.log output

```
post:
author_id: 0
body: "<p>This is the body of the lorem ipsum post</p>"
category_id: null
created_at: "2019-06-13 17:08:45"
excerpt: "This is the excerpt for the Lorem Ipsum Post"
featured: 0
id: 1
image: "posts/post1.jpg"
meta_description: "This is the meta description"
meta_keywords: "keyword1, keyword2, keyword3"
seo_title: null
slug: "lorem-ipsum-post"
status: "PUBLISHED"
title: "Lorem Ipsum Post"
```

screenshot of console.log:
[Screenshot of console.log response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KnjW.png)

Comment: Could you please try by injecting zones in your constructor like this: `constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, ...) {}` and then doing `this.ngZone.run(() => { this.loadedPost = result; })`? If that works I'll add an answer providing some more information.

Comment: that didn't work either

Comment: I think I've found the issue, please check my answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the image of the `console.log(result)` seems like the response is something like this:

```
{
  "post": {
    "title": "..."
  }
}
```

So you'd need to assign your `loadedPost` like this:

```
  // ...
  this.postService.getPost(postId).subscribe((result: any) => {
    console.log('post: ', result.post);
    this.loadedPost = result.post; // <----- I've changed this!
  });
```

And then show the title like this:

```
<ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-title text-center>{{ loadedPost?.title }}</ion-card-title>
</ion-card-header>
```

Please notice that the `?` in `{{ loadedPost?.title }}` is needed because the `loadedPost` property is assigned by an async method, so it will be `undefined` at first until the API returns the response.

Comment: thank you very much! ...this didnt exactly work but it set me in the direction... I'll show what i did below...

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped @captain. May I ask why it didn't work?

Comment: when i do ```result.post``` it gives this error... 
```Property 'post' does not exist on type 'Object'.```

Comment: Oh, I see... Ok, I've updated the answer anyway to fix that typescript error  `.subscribe((result: any) => {...}`; :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add the Elvis operator (?) before the object properties:

loadedPost?.title

This is helpful when the object is being set asynchronously (i.e. with an HTTP request).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-title text-center>{{loadedPost && loadedPost.title}}</ion-card-title>
</ion-card-header>
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as doing `{{ loadedPost?.title }}` which changes nothing compared to what's explained in the OP.

Comment: with ```{{loadedPost?.title}}``` the error goes away but the title is not displayed on the page

Answer (score 0):

i have another solution with asyc, try  this:

in TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { PostService } from '../post.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.page.scss'],
})
export class PostPage implements OnInit {
  loadedPost$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const postId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('postId');

    this.loadedPost$ = this.postService.getPost(postId)
  }
}
```

in HTML

```
<ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-title text-center>{{(loadedPost$ | async)?.title}}</ion-card-title>
</ion-card-header>
```

Comment: @captain are you absolutely sure that the response has a `title` property at the top level of the object? Could you please add to your question the output of `console.log(result)`? This answer should be working unless we're missing something else...

Comment: @captain, for debugger, put this  {{loadedPost$ | async | json }}  in HTML, show us the result

Comment: i just put the console log result in the question

Answer (score 0):

as per what @sebaferreras pointed out in the `console.log(result)`, i did this instead;

```
<ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-title text-center>{{loadedPost?.post.title}}</ion-card-title>
</ion-card-header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) in your html file, like this:`{{ loadedPost?.title }}` or use `ngIf` to check if `loadedPost` is initialized:

```html
<ion-card-header *ngIf="loadedPost">
  <ion-card-title text-center>
    {{loadedPost.title}}
  </ion-card-title>
</ion-card-header>
```